# React-native command not found in Terminal

Tags: macos, react-native, react-native-cli

I keep encountering the "command not found" error when trying to create a new react native project. I've looked through past questions on this topic and they all say to change the PATH, which doesn't seem to work for me.

I tried installing and uninstalling react-native-cli. I've checked and changed the PATH. Nothing works.

```
Davids-MBP-2:~ David$ brew -v
Homebrew >=1.7.1 (shallow or no git repository)
Homebrew/homebrew-core (no git repository)
Davids-MBP-2:~ David$ watchman -v
4.9.0
Davids-MBP-2:~ David$ node -v
v11.13.0
Davids-MBP-2:~ David$ npm install -g react-native-cli
/Users/David/.npm-global/bin/react-native -> /Users/David/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js
+ react-native-cli@2.0.1
updated 1 package in 1.392s
Davids-MBP-2:~ David$ react-native init hello
-bash: react-native: command not found
Davids-MBP-2:~ David$
```

I installed node, homebrew, watchman, and finally react-native. The first three work, but react doesn't.

Comment: npm install -g react-native-cli. I used npm to install homebrew and watchman successfully. And right after tried react but no luck.

Comment: Hmm.. I just want to clarify that you used `brew install node`? What is the output of `npm root -g`?

Comment: this is the output of npm root -g:                         /Users/David/.npm-global/lib/node_modules

Answer (score 0):

You first to make you sure that /usr/local/share/npm/bin is in your PATH to use binaries installed with npm.

Add  following are to your ~/.bashrc:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/share/npm/bin:$PATH"
```

you also sure about that path you install npm pakage.if that can not fullfill your requirement npm from bin then you must uninstall and after fully uninstall you install it again it may be work.It work in my case

Comment: What do I do after adding it to my path? I tried that previously but it didn't work either. I added it to ~/.bash_profile saved, went back called the source to refresh, closed and reopened terminal, yet still nothing.

Comment: you install your react native globally first and then try

Comment: use this step npm install -g react-native-cli

Comment: that's what I did initially

Comment: cool men you must solve your problem form initially  otherwise you forgot about solving problem. thanks

Comment: that makes no sense

Answer (score 0):

I'll first describe the setup on my system.

Check first where `brew install node` installed your `node_modules`.

```
$ npm root -g
/usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

Next, check that the installed scripts/commands are in a corresponding *bin* folder:

```
$ ls -l /usr/local/bin | grep react-native
... react-native -> ../lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js
```

Next, make sure that the *bin* folder is in your `$PATH`.

```
$ echo $PATH
...:/usr/local/bin:...
```

Finally, persist the path to that *bin* folder by adding it to `PATH` in your *~/.bash_profile*.

```
$ cat ~/.bash_profile
...
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
...
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

(I am not sure if your Terminal env need you to do `source ~/.bash_profile` every time you open a new Terminal session.)

---

Now, from your comment, it seems you have your *node_modules* installed in a non-standard folder.

> this is the output of npm root -g: /Users/David/.npm-global/lib/node_modules

Try doing the same steps I mentioned above:

1. Look for the corresponding *bin* folder (maybe in */Users/David/.npm-global/bin/*?)
2. Add the *bin* folder to your `PATH`
3. Persist the modified `PATH` by putting it in your *~/.bash_profile*.

If you can't find the *bin/react-native*, try these:

```
$ find /Users/David/ -name "react-native" -type l
$ find /usr/local/bin -name "react-native" -type l
```

Those commands may take a long time, but it should return something like this:

```
$ find /usr/local/bin -name "react-native" -type l 
/usr/local/bin/react-native
```

Once you've found the path to `react-native` bin, it should just be a matter of adding it your `PATH` and persisting it.